# Script to automate two consecutive ssh connections

Tags: linux, ssh

I know it is possible to write a shell script which passes your hard-coded password to a ssh connection authentication (using expect). However what I need is slightly more complicated.

At my university I have a desktop computer appointed to me. I can connect remotely to this computer by first making a ssh connection with some server, then making another ssh connection from that server to my appointed desktop computer. This goes like:

---

localuser@localcomputer:~$ ssh -X username@serveraddress

username@serveradress password:

server$ ssh -X username@remotecomputeraddress

username@remotecomputeraddress password:

username@remotecomputer:~>

---

Is there a way to write a script which could automate the above (i.e. performing two consecutive ssh connections)?

Thanks in advance!

ps: Both the local and the remote computers are running on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this interactively with:

```
ssh -t -X username@serveraddress ssh -t -X username@remotecomputeraddress
```

Note that is not a pipe - the second `ssh` is the command to run on the connection created by the first `ssh`. The `-t` options are necessary to allocate the pseudo-ttys necessary for interaction (password gathering as well as the ultimate goal - an interactive session on the remote system). Wrapping it up with `expect` left as an exercise for the reader.... ;-)

Bonus points for setting up proper private/public key pairs and `ssh-agent` so that the passwords aren't necessary (unless, of course, that is disallowed for security reasons).

Comment: Dear twalberg,

I have tried your method. I got as far as past the first ssh connection. After this my script halts and only continues when I exit the first ssh connection. What can I do to make it work properly. I have added my script below:

---
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ssh -t -X remoteuser@serveraddress ssh -t -X remoteuser@remotecomputer
expect "remoteuser@serveraddress's password: \r"
send "my_password"
interact
expect "remoteuser@remotecomputer's password: \r"
send "my_password"
interact
---

Comment: Thanks twalberg, I managed to reach my goal with a combination of the -t option and using password-less keys.

Comment: Here I would like to extend this question. Is there any chance to use rsync to transfer files from; lets say server1 to server3 through server2, for example? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.

Presuming you have your except script in the `expect_script`:

```
cat expect_script | ssh -X username@serveraddress sh -s
```

In this expect_script you must run `ssh -X username@remotecomputeraddress`.

And of course you can install public keys on the both hosts and use passwordless authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something to do this with bang paths a while back:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/deep-ssh.html

So you'd set up passwordless, passphraseless authentication (or use an agent for the passphrase), like:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/ssh-keys.html

And then:

```
deep-ssh username@serveraddress!username@remotecomputeraddress command
```

If bash complains about the !, you can just escape it with a backslash.

The old timers will recognize that this is how UUCP paths were specified.